# PLSQL find ascii symbol in blob

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need to find specific ascii symbols in blob, eg. non breaking space (160).
I'm stuck with this code

```
select *
  from tableName
 where dbms_lob.instr (blobColumn,
                   NOT SURE WHAT I SHOULD LOOK FOR,
                   1,
                   1
                    ) > 0
```

I've tried to pass char(160), hextoraw, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

The [documented syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/arpls/DBMS_LOB.html#GUID-5A3CD712-B28B-4A44-AC96-6DACF7991316) is:

> ```sql
> DBMS_LOB.INSTR (
>   lob_loc    IN   BLOB,
>   pattern    IN   RAW,
>   offset     IN   INTEGER := 1,
>   nth        IN   INTEGER := 1)
> RETURN INTEGER;
> ```

So you can use:

```sql
select *
from   tableName
where  dbms_lob.instr(blobColumn, UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(CHR(160)), 1, 1) > 0
```

or:

```sql
select *
from   tableName
where  dbms_lob.instr(blobColumn, HEXTORAW('A0'), 1, 1) > 0
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cqAcMXGK)